# Proving Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like to prove that If $f$ is continuous on $[a, \infty)$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)< \infty$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, \infty)$.

My book contains a lot of theorems that have to do with proving uniform continuity, but all of them require the set to be closed and bounded.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Argue by contradiction. If uniform continuity fails, then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta$ (use $\delta=1/n$) there are two points $x_n,y_n$ with $|x_n-y_n|<1/n$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\ge \epsilon$. Could such a sequence have a convergent subsequence? No. (Why?) Could it be unbounded? Also no. (Why?). QED

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $L = \lim_\infty f$

***Using the limit property:***

$$
\exists A>0: x> A \implies |f(x) - L| \le \frac\epsilon 2
$$

And using the [Heine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem): $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,A + 1]$.

***Using the uniform continuity:***
$$
\exists 0<r<\frac13: |x-x'|<r, \max (x,x') \le A+1 \implies |f(x) - f(x')| \le \epsilon
$$

***Conclusion:***

Let $x\ge a$. If $x<A+\frac 13$ then 
$$
\forall x' \in [x-r,x+r]: |f(x) - f(x')| \le \epsilon
$$
because of the uniform continuity.

And if $x\ge A+\frac13$:

$$
\forall x' \in [x-r,x+r]
|f(x) - f(x')| \le |f(x) - L| + |L-f(x')| \le \epsilon
$$

because of the limit property.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately, our book doesn't introduce the Heine-Cantor theorem, so I can't use your proof.  Thanks anyways!